# How to use tabs + swipe navigation on API level 8

Tags: android, navigation

I was creating an activty with Navigation type of tabs + swipe . But it says that ir requires a minimum API level of 11 and my current minimum is 8. But I've seen many apps having this type of navigation and even running on gingerbread . So I want to ask how to do this on API 8 ?

Comment: By using a [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) and/or [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

Comment: can you explain how to use support library ?

Comment: The page I linked has [a section](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Using) specifically on usage which covers it far better than I can in 500 characters. Oh, and [this page](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=android+how+to+use+support+library) as well.

Answer (score 0):

download pagerIndicator, it is what you want:
[viewpagerindicator.com](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)